Existence of the smooth extension of a discrete submodular and convex-extensible function
A function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ is submodular iff
$$ f(p)+f(q) \geq f(p\vee q) + f(p \wedge q),$$
where $A$ could be $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb Z^n$.
Moreover, a smooth function $h$ is submodular iff
$$ \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \leq 0, \quad \forall i\neq j.$$
A function $g: \mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb R$ is convex-extensible iff there exists a convex function $\bar g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $\bar g|_{\mathbb Z^n} = g$.
My question is:
Can a submodular and convex-extensible function defined on $\mathbb Z^n$ be extended to a smooth function that is submodular and convex?
